# CanvasJs- The chart is cut off its container

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

I am using CanvasJs library to present a chart.
The problem is that the chart is being cut off and not displaying well.
here is an image of the problem:

[image]

you can see that the title is cut off, and also the Y axis description is cut off, not mentioning the columns description....

here's my code (this one is located inside window.onload function)

```
  var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
        backgroundColor: "#d6d9de",
        title: {
            text: "שם הגרף ומה הוא מציג"
        },
        data: [

      {
          dataPoints: [
        { x: 1, y: 297571, label: "Venezuela" },
        { x: 2, y: 267017, label: "Saudi" },
        { x: 3, y: 175200, label: "Canada" },
        { x: 4, y: 154580, label: "Iran" }
        ]
      }
      ]
    });

    chart.render();
```

and I also have the html div in which the contains graph

```
<div id="chartContainer" style="width:100%; height:300px;"/>
```

Please help!

Comment: Could you post the wrapper element of the div#container css settings if exists?

Comment: It does not matter, event when I put it as the only div in the body section it happens...

Comment: The fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/zLq77us8/  created with your given options is working fine. Can you create a fiddle reproducing the same issue?